# Hostname on tomcat welcome page

Tags: html, linux, jsp, tomcat8, hostname

I have one load-balancer and two tomcat instances, when I hit my load balancer I want to see hostname of server that served this page.

How to add hostname of server on tomcat served page?

Comment: Shorter and cleaner title, question is more clear

Comment: I've resolved this by adding index.html to the ROOT folder, since the servlet is pre-configured to pick up the .html files first and I have a bash script which will write the hostname to a file, I'm reading and displaying that file from the index.html.